# OSX errors - AMFI: "Allowing exception handler because the process is not restricted"

Tags: linux, macos, kernel

Since I have upgraded my Mac to Sierra I see tons of messages in the Console says a specific process is not restricted.
What could cause this error ?
Is it something the process does ? access to protected folder ? is there any alternative way to launch the process to overcome this message ?
This is the exact message

kernel  AMFI: allowing exception handler for '' (59273) because the process is not restricted.

Answer (score 1):

No answer either, just adding more to the thread. My MBP has been running very slowly, I finally checked Console and see this error repeated thousands of times:[image]

I am unable to properly shut down or restart my computer. After shutdown or restart, I see a black screen but the backlight is still on (Apple logo on the back is lit up).  I have to hold the power button for ~5 seconds to shut down. Then when I turn the machine on, I see a warning message that my computer was not shut down properly.

Comment: I found the issue for my system, I was running `boot2docker init` in my `.bash_profile`, but boot2docker was a very old version. I removed this init and my issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an answer, just adding symptoms. Got the same issue (booting verbose), except my system doesn't even get through boot process anymore.

Resolved it by a full reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Just found something which could give a clue for this print,
When adding to the code "__asm int 3;" (which is debug break in order to avoid process debugging) every time the CPU hits this assembly line (even if not attached to debugger) the Console prints this restricted message.

Is there anyway to call "__asm int 3;" without this message print ?

Answer (score 0):

Same here.
Only difference is that I may see some disk errors as

```
disk0s2: I/O error.
disk0s2: I/O error.
disk0s2: I/O error.
disk0s2: I/O error.
disk0s2: I/O error.
```

Ok Solved My problem.

What I Did:

1. Entered on SINGLE mode [[1]](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573);
2. fsck -fy /dev/disk0s2

runned it 2-3 times where bad blocks were marked after that everything was OK. But be aware that I must replace HD